# How to add new item to itemscontrol at the same time updating the existing items in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

It is very tough to explain my problem but I will give a try.

I have a ItemsControl with a ItemTemplate which has button, on clicking the button I have to add new Item to the ItemsControl. And the last row should only have the button.

**PROBLEM**
I was able to hide the buttons of the rows(except last) initially during binding but on clicking the button and adding dynamic row I am not able to hide the previous button.

Hope I have explained my problem. If it is not clear enough please let me know. I am not able to solve this.

Here is my implementation

**My MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableCollectionUpdation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ObservableCollectionUpdation"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IsLastItemConverter x:Key="LastItemConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl x:Name="RecordsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Records}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TotalCount}"></TextBlock>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Add" Command="{Binding ElementName=RecordsControl, Path= DataContext.AddCommand}"
                                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                Converter={StaticResource LastItemConverter}}"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MyViewModel, Record and Command Classes**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand AddCommand { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoAdd);
        Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>
        {
            new Record {Name = "One", TotalCount =1},
            new Record{Name="Second", TotalCount=1}
        };
    }

    private void DoAdd()
    {
        Records.Add( new Record
        {
            Name = "Added",
            TotalCount = Records.Count + 1
        });
        OnPropertyChanged("Records");
    }
}


public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}

public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _executeMethod;

    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod)
    {
        _executeMethod = executeMethod;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeMethod.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class IsLastItemConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)value;
            ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

            return (ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) == ic.Items.Count - 1) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                                  object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you have a ONE Add Button outside the itemscontrol?

Comment: yea that's what I would do

Comment: It is not about the button I want to control the itemscontrol. Button is just an example in my POC. @blindmeis

Comment: you dont need to control the items control you just need to control your collection in your viewmodel. the itemscontrol is just for showing your collection. nevertheless an easy would be to add a new property (IsLastItem) to your Record object so you can bind to it and you can easy set the property in your Add Command

Comment: So every time I add a new record I have to traverse through the collection and update the IsLastItem property? @blindmeis

Comment: I have found better solution to recreate the collection again posted the answer below. Thanks for the help.

Comment: like i said - i would put the button outside :) so i would not have any problem and no converter. but if you need the button on last row. then there are different ways to change the "IsLastItem" property. you could use linq to get the last and set the true for the new one. you can remember the Record with true in a field and just change it to false and true for the new one and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this efficient solution but here is what I found to fix it. That is rebind the collection to the control so changing the DoAdd method to recreate the `ObservableCollection` solved the issue

```
        private void DoAdd()
        {
            Records.Add( new Record
            {
                Name = "Added",
                TotalCount = Records.Count + 1
            });

            Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>(Records);
            OnPropertyChanged("Records");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is that converter is called for each row individually, and when that row is being evaluated, that is the last row and hence all are visible

There can be several ways to handle this, easiest being, have your new Item as a property and only when newItem changes update visibility

Comment: Why is not re-evaluating each row, the collection it self is changed right.
How can I solve it? @Muds

Comment: Quite didn't get, but I am adding new Item to the collection not updating it right @Muds

Comment: you need a reference to last row item and then you can play with its visibility .. so have last added item as a property in view model, may be you can also bind that to selected item and then change selected item style